# Implementing imagesc in C

Tags: c, image, matlab, image-processing

I am in need of C version(not C++) of [`imagesc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imagesc.html) function in MATLAB. I am in conversion of a MATLAB program to C(It is the requirement). The only thing left to implement is `imagesc` functionality. I don't necessarily need to plot or show the image in a window. I can write the image to a bitmap file also. So in essence, I need a matrix of RGB color values or grayscale color values as the result of this implementation.

So, I am looking for a simple library that is portable to Windows and Linux, and also dothe above. Or, I am ready to implement one of my own. But, I don't have a clue on how to do that. If there is no such library, would you please provide some information on implementing it?

Answer (score 2):

Man, did you do a single Google search? There's tons of image manipulation libraries for C. [ImageMagick's C library](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-wand.php) is one decent example, but if you don't like it you have many options.

Comment: I have seen that already, but I need a very simple library. I only need the `imagesc` functionality.

Comment: So what? Don't use the extra functionality then. Is executable size a dire issue for your project?

Answer (score 0):

Look at [OpenCV](http://opencv.org), a computer vision and image processing library that works with C and C++. To accomplish something similar to **imagesc** in C++, I use the functions [imread and imshow](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/display_image/display_image.html) or alternatively I load the data in a [Mat](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html) structure and I display it with imshow.